# Laravel image save as .tmp in the db even though the file uploaded in the correct folder

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, image

I'm trying to add a user to the database in Laravel.

following is my User Model.

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail {
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'image_id',       
        'country_id',
        'email',
        'password',
        'gender',
        'date_of_birth',
        'region_id',
        'role_id',
        'is_email_verified'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

And this is my User Controller.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use DB;
use Hash;

class UserController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index(Request $request) {
        $data = User::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);

        return view('admins.users.index',compact('data'))
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create() {
        $roles = Role::pluck('name','name')->all();

        return view('admins.users.create',compact('roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $data = $request->input('roles');
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $key = 'data' . $key;
            $$key = $value;
        }

        $roleid=$data0;

        if($roleid=='Admin') {
            $roleid='1';    
        } else if($roleid=='Regional Admin') {
            $roleid='2'; 
        } else {
            $roleid='3'; 
        }

        $request->merge(['role_id' => ''.$roleid.'']);
        $request->merge(['gender' => 'M']);
        $request->merge(['date_of_birth' => '1992-01-11']);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|same:confirm-password',
            'roles' => 'required',
            'image_id' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'role_id'=>'required',
            'gender'=>'required',
            'date_of_birth'=>'required'
        ]);
        
        if ($image = $request->file('image_id')) {
            $destinationPath = 'propics/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image_id'] = $profileImage;
            $request->merge(['image_id' => $profileImage]);
        }
        //$input['role_id']=$request->input('roles');
        dd($request->all());

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
        $user = User::create($input);
        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

        return redirect()->route('users.index')
            ->with('success','User created successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function show($id) {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('admins.users.show',compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id) {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $roles = Role::pluck('name','name')->all();
        $userRole = $user->roles->pluck('name','name')->all();

        return view('admins.users.edit',compact('user','roles','userRole'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
            'password' => 'same:confirm-password',
            'roles' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();
        if(!empty($input['password'])) {
            $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
        } else {
            $input = array_except($input,array('password'));    
        }
        
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->update($input);
        DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id',$id)->delete();
        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

        return redirect()->route('admins.users.index')
            ->with('success','User updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id) {
        User::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('admins.users.index')
            ->with('success','User deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

Now my question is that this stores my users in the DB perfectly but the user image stores as .tmp.

The file also get uploaded into the correct folder, but when it stores in the DB it stores as,

```
C:\xampp\tmp\phpA031.tmp
```

instead of .png or .jpg

Where should I correct my code?

Comment: Can you please remove code from your controller that is not relevant to your issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
    public function store(Request $request){

$post = new Post([
   'title'=>$request->get('title'),
   'description'=>$request->get('description')
]);

$imageName = $request->title.'.png';
$request->image->move(public_path('images/posts'),$imageName);

$post->save();
return redirect()->back();
}
```

now you create view and create 3 input fields: name title (text), description (textarea) and image (file)